Contradiction: If and only If, an apparent "shortcut". What is the mistake?
I noticed something while I was proving an if and only if statement, and it seems to provide a "shortcut" that I haven't seen before. Say I want to prove $A \Leftrightarrow B$.
For $A \rightarrow B$, I assumed $A \rightarrow \neg B$ and, for the sake of discussion, I showed that it led to a contradiction. Hence $A \rightarrow B$ must be true.
For $B \rightarrow A$, assume for the sake of contradiction $B \rightarrow \neg A$ holds. Now, the contrapositive must also hold: $A \rightarrow \neg B$. But since $A \rightarrow \neg B$ is a contradiction via the above, then our assumption that $B \rightarrow \neg A$ must be false. Therefore,  $B \rightarrow A$ must hold.
Hence, $A \Leftrightarrow B$ is true. Is my reasoning valid? My confusion is that usually I need to do two different "sets of work" to prove both directions, but here I seem to get the right to left "for free" somewhat, by proving the left to right direction.

Proof of $A\to B$ by contradiction would be by assuming $\neg(A\to B)$, i.e. assuming $A\land \neg B$, and hence proving some statement in the form $X\land \neg X$. Proof of $A\to B$ by contrapositive would be proving $\neg B\to \neg A$. More of the same for the other half.

$\neg(A \to \neg B)$ does not imply $A\to B$. That's where the mistake is. Your second paragraph is incorrect.

$A\to\lnot B$ is not true if and only if $A,B$ are both true. It’s not the same as $A\to B$.

Is $A$ a formula or a proposition?

$(A\implies \lnot B) \ne \lnot (A\implies B)$.  And $\lnot(A\implies \lnot B) \ne (A\implies B) $.  Instead $\lnot(A\implies \lnot B)= \lnot(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)=A\land B$ which is a stronger statement than either $A\implies B$ or $A\iff B$.  But you won't necessarily get a contradiction assuming $A\implies \lnot B$. $A:= 2+3=6$ and $B:= 9$ is prime.  $A\iff B$ is true.  But If we assume $2+3=6\implies 9$ is composite we will not get a contradiction.

Notice $\neg (B\rightarrow A)$ is $\neg (\neg B \lor A)\equiv (B\land \neg A)$, which is not $(\neg B \lor \neg A)\equiv (B\rightarrow \neg A)$ (take $B$ to be false, then $(B\rightarrow \neg A) $ would be true and $(B\land \neg A)$ would be false). Also, it is possible for $((A\rightarrow B)\land (A\rightarrow \neg B))$ to be true (just take $A$ to be false), there's no a priori contradiction in both being true.
If you somehow knew that $((A\rightarrow B)\land \neg (A\rightarrow \neg B))$, then you'd have $((\neg A\lor B)\land\neg(\neg A\lor \neg B))$ which is equivalent to $((\neg A\lor B)\land (A\land B))\equiv (A\land B).$
